# Regroup in django returning only one grouper - not iterating on regrouped list

Tags: python, django, templatetags

I have a simple ListView of a Model with a DateTimeField, the Model is ordered by this field. In the template, I have the following code:

```
  {% regroup teamsession_list by tdate|date:"W" as weekly_list %}
    {% for training_week in weekly_list %}
    <div class="container">
      {{training_week}}</div>{% endfor %}
```

I wrote this to test the returned result. I have four weeks of data, but only one grouper returned in the template  like so

```
GroupedResult(grouper='48', list=[<TeamSession: xesr: performed on 2018-11-27 00:00:00+00:00>, <TeamSession: test4: performed on 2018-11-26 00:00:00+00:00>, <TeamSession: test5: performed on 2018-11-26 00:00:00+00:00>, <TeamSession: test: performed on 2018-11-26 00:00:00+00:00>])
```

Anyone with an idea why the other four week is not in the result?

The view looks like this:

```
class TeamWeeklyView(ListView):
    model=models.TeamSession
    template_name = 'teams/weekly.html'
```

I know there is a weekly archive view, but its not suitable for my purposes.

Comment: Have you implemented this in a view?As for documentation, that need to be done, using the QuerySet APIs for aggregation functions : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#aggregation-functions and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: yes I did since the problem is with the template tag I had to. The issue is that the regroup only shows one week of data. If I don't regroup, I can access all the elements of the queryset.

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't know why, but simply changing the 'training_week' into item did the trick. I changed nothing else.